# INSERT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE и LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: mysql, innodb

Согласно ответам к вопросу на [en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778534/mysql-on-duplicate-key-last-insert-id) пришёл к выводу, что обозначенные там инструменты - это то, что требуется в моей задаче, а именно: получить идентификатор "вставленной" строки, даже если этого по факту и не произошло.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (1, 'tra-ta-ta')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
```

... при этом колонка `id` - `PRIMARY KEY` и `AUTO_INCREMENT`, а колонка `text` - `UNIQUE`.

Но исходя из этого кода получается, что `id` будет заменён (знак присваивания, как бы, на это намекает):

```
`id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
```

Означает ли это, что значение идентификатора в соответствующей колонке действительно будет заменено (пусть и на тоже самое значение) с соответствующими последствиями, как то, например, срабатывание `ON UPDATE CASCADE` для `FOREIGN KEY` у какой-нибудь подключенной таблицы? А может и `ON DELETE CASCADE` сработает, как в случае, если использовать `REPLACE` вместо `INSERT`? Тогда совсем беда.

Прав ли я в своих сомнениях, и если это действительно так, то каким образом возможно решить проблему?

Comment: Ваши сомнения - прекрасны. Но, если вы напишите предмет вашего вопроса (чего достичь хотите), и необходимые данные - конечно же в начале вопроса, то все будет просто замечательно! А пока - туман, ведомый одному человеку - вам.

Comment: Возможно, что это глупость (вечером я не работник) , но что мешает сделать эксперимент? Посмотреть, как поведут себя тригеры

Comment: @Majestio, второй раз Вы мне указываете, как оформлять вопросы. Оставьте. При внимательном прочтении он вполне понятен. Если лично Вам понимание затруднительно, прошу впредь игнорировать.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, я триггеры не использую, а вот внешние ключи - да. Подумал, что вопрос получит ответ значительно быстрее, нежели чем я докопаюсь до сути, испробовав все варианты на возможные исключения. В конце концов ситуация с использованием `on duplicate update`, как мне кажется, вполне обыденная для тех, кто постоянно работает с СУБД.

Comment: @alexis031182 , договорились. Я постараюсь запомнить ваше пожелание. И, тем не менее, если вы "желаете, чтобы вам сделали хорошо", обозначьте детали. Это, имхо, нормальная практика.

Comment: @Majestio, я обозначил всё, что меня интересует в этом вопросе. Перечислил конкретные sql-конструкции, которые могут создать, на мой взгляд, проблему (в чём собственно и опасения). Какие ещё детали могут быть необходимы для понимания вопроса, не могу представить.

Comment: @alexis031182 , представить не сложно - 1) DDL используемых таблиц, 2) Описание желаемого результата ... И только потом ваши попытки его достичь. Ответом может быть - исправление "ваших попыток", либо кардинально иное решение. Без обид. Просто запомните - "в правильно-поставленном вопросе содержится 50% правильного ответа".

Comment: @Majestio, мне понятно то, о чём Вы говорите. Я на этом сайте достаточно давно. Единственное, в моём вопросе совершенно ни к чему излишняя детализация. Вся ситуация становится ясна из одного единственного запроса, приведённого в вопросе. Ну и собственно это подтвеждает наличие ответа к моему вопросу.

Comment: @alexis031182 , вполне возможно, и я даже не спорю. Но, за окном четверг. У многих (по крайней мере - у меня) телепатические возможности на значительном спаде. Считаю, нужно таким, как я, давать скидку на понимание. Хотя, конечно, ваш вопрос - и решать вам.

Comment: @Majestio, не знаю, о какой телепатии и скидке на понимание идёт речь, т.к. вопрос более чем конкретен. Что именно Вам в нём непонятно? Смущает слово "сомнения"? Воспринимайте как синоним для обозначения вопросов, раскрытых в предыдущем абзаце в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @alexis031182 , забейте)  Я был неправ!)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51674/discussion-between-majestio-and-alexis031182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> create table `table` (id serial, `text` varchar(16) unique);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (1, 'tra-ta-ta')
    ->  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `table`;
+----+-----------+
| id | text      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | tra-ta-ta |
+----+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (2, 'tro-lo-lo')
    ->  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select * from `table`;
+----+-----------+
| id | text      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | tra-ta-ta |
|  2 | tro-lo-lo |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `text`) VALUES (3, 'tra-ta-ta')
    ->  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from `table`;
+----+-----------+
| id | text      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | tra-ta-ta |
|  2 | tro-lo-lo |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Как мы видим, в третьем запросе на пополнение/изменение

> Query OK, **0 rows affected** (0.00 sec)

Да, у MySQL есть такая особенность - он считает обновлением только **фактическое** обновление. Т.е. связанное с тем, что итоговые данные **не равны** исходным.

**UPD:** Где-то накосячил. Чую, но сообразить не могу, слишком вечер. Завтра раскопаю всё и отпишусь.

Comment: Есть. Например, касательно обозначенного в тексте вопроса `foreign key`.

Comment: То есть _Query OK, **0 rows affected** (0.00 sec)_ Вы благополучно просмотрели?

Comment: Я не очень понимаю причину Вашего тона. Вероятно я задал чрезвычайно простой вопрос, но это исходит из моего малого опыта работы с СУБД. Вы просто бросили листинг кода, не особо объяснив (собственно, как и в прошлый раз), что с чем связано и из чего вытекает. "0 rows affected" я увидел, но не связал это с внешними ключами.

Comment: MySQL считает обновлением только ФАКТИЧЕСКОЕ обновление. Т.е. связанное с тем, что итоговые данные НЕ РАВНЫ исходным. Только в этом случае будут стрелять триггеры и протчая... мне казалось, что это общеизвестно до тривиальности...

Comment: На сайте собираются люди разного уровня подготовки. В разных областях. Даже если так случится, что конкретно сам вопрошающий и вполне себе неплохо знаком с темой, тем не менее потом придут другие читатели, кто, возможно, будет не столь отягощён соответствующими знаниями. Поэтому в любом случае полезно дать ответ, поясняющий принципиальные моменты. Ну а что касаемо меня, я этой особенности действительно не знал. Вынесите её в ответ, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас сделаем... готово.

Comment: Akina, и если возможно - ссылку на пруфы. Это будет крайне познавательно. Ящетаю)